# Can't Emulate already exist email function- Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a condition where i wand to go from text field to another because i want a function to be called when i do this step. To be more Clear i will add some images.

[image]

UI:

[image]

Gif:

[image]
Html :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 no-padding-sides input-container">
   <label class="col-xs-4 no-padding-sides">Email Address </label>
   <input type="email" class="col-xs-8 custom-input-styles" formControlName="email" (blur)="checkIfExists()"
      autocomplete="off">
   <span *ngIf="step2Form.get('email').invalid && (step2Form.get('email').dirty || step2Form.get('email').touched)"
      class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-4 no-padding-sides  slideDown">
   <span *ngIf="step2Form.get('email').errors.required" class=" form-error slideDown">
   Invalid Email
   </span>
   <span *ngIf="step2Form.get('email').errors.emailExists" class="form-error slideDown">
  Email already exist
   </span>

   </span>
</div>
```

this what i want to emulate

```
(blur)="checkIfExist()"
```

Method i tried :

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email Address'])[1]/following::input[1]")).SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

I want this symbol to go down to phone number text field because as i said when this happen a pop up message will occure and notify me that this email already exist

Comment: Y9u need to send tab key to the email field so that focus goes to phone number field that will invoke the application's code of checking if email is duplicate or not and show the pop-up

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant _HTML_?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i tried what you are talking about before i ask this question but didn't worked

Comment: @DebanjanB i didn't understand

Comment: I guess this is an e2e test? So you need to simulate user inputs. Either you simulate a click in the bottom input control, or, as mentioned above, simulate a tab key. You may need to check if it is possible to navigate from one input to another in that application via tab key.

Comment: @nilsK i tried send key and didn't worked

Comment: Does it work when you start that application (without selenium) and use your tab key? What about simulating a click to the input field?

Comment: Also share your code part where you tried to send TAB and html, it will be helpful

Comment: @nilsK yes worked without selenium work. i tried to click on the other element but also with nothing worked

Comment: Please show some code! Test-method and relevant UI template.

Comment: check now please

Comment: @nilsK 
Check again please the question (html )

Comment: @sers check please

Answer (score 0):

Try to click to the Phone Number field without selenium and check if popup appears, if does click with Selenuim.

Clicks:

```
driver.FindElement(phone number input locator).click();

Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);
actionProvider.DoubleClick(driver.FindElement(phone number input locator));
```

SendKeys:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
driver.FindElement(phone number input locator).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']")).SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
```

Change focus to another element with Javascript:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus()", phoneNumberElement); //or to any button
```

Also try to send tab key to parent div element of the email input:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']/ancestor::div[1]")).SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']/ancestor::div[1]")).SendKeys(Keys.Tab);

the method above is not reachable by keyboard. Yes everything worked correctly without selenium even if i click on phone number but  with selenium not worked

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The element reference of <input class="col-xs-8 custom-input-styles ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" type="text"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at

Comment: Which element is stale?

Comment: phone number is stale

Comment: ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus()", phoneNumberElement);

Comment: Change it to `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus()", driver.FindElement(whatever locator you use));`

Comment: you code is correct but sorry didn't worked as i want test

Comment: If can provide url I'll try to help you

Comment: it's local server man. I will add a gif to show you how it's look

Comment: check it please

Comment: i can't man because this isn't for me..But i shared with you the important part of the code

Comment: All the options that I can now offer to try are in the answer

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are able to move the control from email text field to Phone number field, But the expected behaviour as shown in gif is not working with selenium.

The browser in gif seems to be chrome, are you trying to execute on Chrome with selenium as well? 
And also are you working with any browser profile or browser options with this?

**I suspect that in either profile or browser options there may be an option declared to avoid unwanted alerts/popups, So the browser invoked by chrome forcefully kills the pop up.**

If that is the case, you can try something similar to this to allow popups in browser invoked by selenium

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```